# Differentiating $ f(x)= \frac{x + \sin x}{x - \cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Can someone help me? I'm having some trouble with this:
how can I differentiate $$ f(x)= \frac{x  + \sin x}{x - \cos x} \quad ?$$

P.S. Is there any trick or something to derive this kind of limit? 
Thanks!

Comment: By "derive", do you mean differentiate?

Comment: Yep, sorry! haha English is my second language

Comment: No problem, just want to make sure I'm answering your question :)

Comment: I suggest using `\frac{}{}` instead of `{ \over }`; [see this TeX.SE thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/27533).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find $f'(x)$, use the quotient rule:

$$f'(x) = \frac{(x-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x)) - (x + \sin(x))(1+\sin(x))}{(x-\cos(x))^{2}}$$

Can you simplify the algebra from here?

Comment: Thank you! that was my doubt! I didn't know if I should separate the sum or not! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of problem where you want to take advantage of the quotient rule:

$$\text{Given}\;\;f(x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)},\quad f'(x) = \frac{g(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{\left(g(x)\right)^2}$$

In your case, we have $$f(x)= \frac{x  + \sin x}{x - \cos x}$$

$$\mathrm{Letting}\;\; g(x) = x + \sin x, \;\;g'(x) = 1 +\cos x\,; \\ \quad\mathrm{and }\quad h(x) = x - \cos x,\;\;h'(x) = 1 + \sin x$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{\left[(1+\cos x)(x-\cos x)\right] - \left[(x + \sin x)(1+\sin x)\right]}{(x-\cos x)^{2}}$$

Of course, you'll want to simplify!

Comment: Clean write up! =1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the product rule for this on the function $f(x)=(x+\sin{x})(x-\cos{x})^{-1}$.

The product rule states that for $f(x)=u\cdot v$, $f'(x)=u\cdot v'+ v\cdot u'$.

So we have: $$f'(x)=(x+\sin{x})(-1)(1+\sin{x})(x-\cos{x})^{-2}+(x-\cos{x})^{-1}(1+\cos{x})$$

Alternatively, you can use the quotient rule. The quotient rule states that for $f(x)=u/v$, $f'(x)=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$

So you have:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(1+\cos{x})(x-\cos{x})-(x+\sin{x})(1+\sin{x})}{(x-\cos{x})^2}$$

These two expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$f'\left(\dfrac{u}{v}\right)=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)h(x)-g(x)h'(x)}{h^2(x)}$$